# DataTable with childrows (sub-dataTables). How can I create/expand ALL sub-dataTables by default?

Tags: datatables, datatables-1.10

I have a dataTable with sub dataTables and I can't make them be expanded on every page. I can make them be expanded on the current page, but when I go to another page, the subtables aren't displayed. It appears as though the child row exists but no dataTable has been created. If I collapse and then expand the childrow the dataTable is created.

Here is my fiddle that I forked from gyrocode.com
https://jsfiddle.net/jsfiddlertwo/8rmq3foy/

Here is the expand button function

```
$('#btn-show-all-children').on('click', function(){
    // Enumerate all rows
    table.rows().every(function(){
        // If row has details collapsed
        if(!this.child.isShown()){
            // Open this row
            this.child(format(this.data())).show();
            childTable(this.data());
            $(this.node()).addClass('shown');
        }
    });
});
```

My format function creates the html for the sub-dataTable

```
function format ( d ) {
    var childId = d.extn;
  return '<div><table id=\'child-table' + childId + '\' class=\'table-striped table-bordered\'></table></div>';
}
```

The childTable function creates the sub-dataTable

```
var childTable = $(childId).DataTable({
    colReorder: true,
    searching: false,
    info: false,
    paging: false,
    scrollY: false,
    data: data.children,
    columns: [{
        title: "Name",
        render: function(data, type, row, meta) {
          return row.name;
        }
      },
      {
        title: "Class",
        render: function(data, type, row, meta) {
          return row.class;
        }
      },
    ]
    });
}
```

The expand button expands and shows the sub-dataTables on the current page. The trouble is that when I go to another page, the sub-dataTables aren't there. Once on another page I can click on the row twice (to collapse and then re-expand) and the sub-dataTables are created.
I've tried using the drawcallback but it is called before the new page is created.

How can I make the sub-dataTables be created on all pages?

Comment: Loop through all the tr in tbody, after table is initialized, and open them. You can add this in `initComplete` callback

Comment: Only the current page's sub-dataTables are created. When I go to another page the sub-dataTables aren't created.

Comment: @Gyrocode.com I don't know how to unmark this question as duplicate. Should I create a new question? How do I let Gyrocode.com know that I don't think it's a duplicate?

Comment: @user2308828, I reopened your question as it make more sense now after you edited it. It would have been reopened by others after review, no need to post duplicate questions.